# Executing a curl command on the client side

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, debian

Let us say that I am running on a Debian machine a server with `sudo python3 -m http.server`. Are there possibilities to execute some `curl` command on the client-side if he opens the website?

My idea is to provide an installation page for my program, so if the user opens it (`http://127.0.0.1/install`), the commands would be automatically executed in the background. I am aware that there are security reasons why this shouldn't be possible, but let's say the user is okay with it. :)

I have found online something about `cgi python scripts`, but I never found any example to do what I want and that is why I am not really sure if it is the right thing or not.

Comment: For debian server, you should have admin access. If you don't have then it will not work. Fast work is to install virtual environment on your project directory.

Comment: Hey, I do have admin access :D